# smarty not working on new server PHP Version 5.2.6

Tags: php, smarty

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: repeated subpattern is too long at offset 18454 in /Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 454

Fatal error: Smarty error: [in login.tpl line 1]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: php (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 455)

this message coming.. it was working perfect on dev server but on live server its not working.

Dev php version was  5.2.14
new server has PHP Version 5.2.6

is this the problem?

Comment: i updated php version to Php 2.6.17 and all working well now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What smarty version are you using?

This thread seems to imply it has to do with a combination of Smarty versions and php version:
http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14563

For most users the sollution seems to be to downgrade Smarty from 2.6.21 to 2.6.20

It's kind of an old thread though, so check if it applies, but it seems akin to your problem.

Comment: That sounds like a weird version number :) Do you mean smarty? or 5.2.17 ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Which version you are using ?

Use the latest version of smarty it might solve your problem.